# Is it always possible to calculate the limit of an elementary function.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let be more precise: define an "strong elementary function" by only admitting rational for the "constant function" in the usual definition of "elementary" function (see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). Let $a$ be an "elementary real" if the constant function $f(x)=a$ is a strong elementary function. With this definition some non rational reals are elementary (for example $\pi = 4\cdot \arctan(1)$); but there are reals that are not elementary. Now let $f(x)$ be a strong elementary function defined in an open interval of an elementary real $a$ with the possible exception of $a$. Suppose that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$$ exists. Is this limit necessarily an elementary real?

The idea behind this question is the following: when we learn to calculate limits in elementary calculus, it seems that there is always a method to do it. By calculating a limit we mean to define it by means of the rationals and elementary functions. But is there a general argument that prove that it is always possible?

Comment: Yes, since all 'elementary functions' are continious in their domains.

Comment: But I allow $a$ to be outside the domain of $f(x)$.

Comment: One can expand in power series, since it only requires computing derivatives. The coefficients will be elementary reals. If it is possible to decide when an elementary real is zero, then the answer is yes if not, then the answer is not.

Comment: Is that clear? The problem is that I do not assume that $f(x)$ is defined in $a$; only that the limit exists. The function $f(x)=x\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is elementary but it is quite pathological in 0 (not derivable). In this case we can prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=0$ but what if we combine such pathological functions with others. It does not seems that we can derivative or take Taylor series.

Comment: @olivier What I said works over the complex numbers since an isolated singularity with infinite principal part in the Laurent expansion (not Taylor) will not have limit. Working on the reals is not as simple.

Comment: @AOlov can you elaborate, what exactly do you mean by power series? You cannot (generally) derivate in $a$, because the functions involved are not necessarily defined in $a$. Nothing prevent you to use the pathological $f(x)$ described above to make even more pathological function. What do you mean by "deciding that an elementary real is 0" either it is or it is not. My precise question does not ask for an algorithm to compute limits. only if they can be expressed by an elementary real.

Comment: Since $a$ is an isolated singularity you can expand in [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) I didn't notice that your question was only about the nature of the limit. The answer for the limit in the complex plane at least it is going to be yes, since it is going to be equal to the term of degree zero in the expansion.

Comment: Hmm? You write "when we learn to calculate limits ... it seems there is always a method to do it". What is your method for calculating $\gamma$? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Mascheroni_constant)

Comment: @AOlov I can believe that your answer may work if you work entirely on the complex plane. But can you transfer the result to the original question concerning the real numbers. It seems that your argument does not work for $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$. Although the limit is 0 over the real.

Comment: @Rob Arthan. When we "calculate" integral, we quickly find functions that cannot be expressed with elementary functions. I have never seen such thing for calculating a limit. The usual tricks (Hospital rule, etc...) seems always to work in the end. Hence my question.

Comment: @olivier: so how are you calculating $\gamma$ using the first formula on the Wikipedia page I cited? It involves no integrals.

Comment: @RobArthan That is not the limit of an elementary function.

Comment: @Rob Arthan. $\gamma$ is defined with the limit of a series. It is not defined as the limit of an elementary function at some point (see the precise formulation of my question). The function from which we take the limit os not elementary.

Comment: Now asked also on MO: [Is it always possible to calculate the limit of an elementary function?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/295425)